# Getting error while executing program to swipe down the screen using Appium

Tags: android, selenium-webdriver, appium

I am getting an error while executing program to swipe down the screen using Appium.

Whilst the code works fine for a swipe right or left, I  get an error when swiping down the screen.
I am almost banging my head for few days. Please help. I have attached the code and the error message for your review.

Thanks in advance.

### code:-

```
public class SwipeScreen {
    AndroidDriver dr;
    @Test
    public void testApp() throws MalformedURLException, InterruptedException{
    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities("appWaitActivity", null, null);
    File app =new File(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\app\\net.one97.paytm (1).apk");
    capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "android"); 
     capabilities.setCapability("deviceName","samsung-gt_i9060-42035bec4397 c000");
      capabilities.setCapability("PlatformVersion","4.2.2");
      capabilities.setCapability("PlatformName","Android");
      capabilities.setCapability("app",app.getAbsolutePath());
     // capabilities.setCapability("appPackage","com.android.settings");
     // capabilities.setCapability("appActivity","com.android.settings.SettingsTabActivity");
      dr = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://192.168.10.165:4723/wd/hub"),capabilities);
      dr.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(4, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    Thread.sleep(50000);
    System.out.println(dr.manage().window().getSize().getWidth());
    System.out.println(dr.manage().window().getSize().getHeight());
    int screenWidth = dr.manage().window().getSize().getWidth();
    int screenHeight = dr.manage().window().getSize().getHeight();
    //Swipe Right
    int startx = screenWidth*8/9;
    int endx = screenWidth/9;
    int starty = screenHeight/2;
    int endy = screenHeight/2;
    dr.swipe(startx, starty, endx, endy, 5000);
    Thread.sleep(50000);
     //Swipe Left
    startx = screenWidth/9;
    endx = screenWidth*8/9;
    starty = screenHeight/2;
    endy = screenHeight/2;
    dr.swipe(startx, starty, endx, endy, 5000);
    Thread.sleep(50000);
    //swipe down
    startx = screenWidth/2;
    endx = screenWidth/2;
    starty = screenHeight*6/7;
    endy = screenHeight/5;
    dr.swipe(startx, starty, endx, endy, 10000);
    Thread.sleep(50000);
    //swipe up
    startx = screenWidth/2;
    endx = screenWidth/2;
    starty = screenHeight/6;
    endy = screenHeight*5/6;
    dr.swipe(startx, starty, endx, endy, 5000);

    }

}
```

### Error:-

```
org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Could not start a new session.  
Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.
Build info: version: '2.43.1', revision: '5163bce', time: '2014-09-10 16:27:58'
System info: host: 'Halcyon2-PC', ip: '192.168.140.172', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.7.0_67'
Driver info: driver.version: AndroidDriver
```

Comment: Can you make sure your appium server is running. Error says its unable to reach appium server

Comment: > info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Swiping from [x=240.0, y=685.0] to [x=240.0, y=160.0] with steps: 280
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Returning result: {"value":"The swipe did not complete successfully","status":13}
> info: [debug] Responding to client with error: {"status":13,"value":{"message":"An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command.","origValue":"The swipe did not complete successfully"},"sessionId":"8074bc5f-24b3-47b1-b6f8-e2343f941817"}

Answer (score 0):

As your problem was already mentioned few times on the Internet with no strict solution:[link1](https://github.com/appium/appium/issues/4662) [link2](https://github.com/appium/appium/issues/1151) [link3](https://github.com/appium/appium/issues/4268)

I'll post here line of code which you can try to implement. It does the job for me.

```
action.press(startX1,startY1).waitAction(2000).moveTo(endX1,endY1).release().perform();
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but still getting the same issue. it's completing the task and throwing exception.

Comment: It looks like that the problem may be connected not exactly with the swipe function, but with the server browser itself.

Maybe try changing IP of the server to localhost (if you can of course), set different port number and make sure to stop and re-lunch appium framework after every lunch. Also you can clear the reports folder before trying.

Comment: Code is working fine for left swipe and right swipe but I have issue while swiping down only. I am using a Samsung mobile whose android version is 4.2.2. my Appium version is 1.4.0.0 and java client version is 3.1.0. May be I have problem with versions??

Comment: Same issue here .Swipe down is working fine on all devices except Samsung (OS - 5.1.1). This bug is device specific

Comment: In this case you can define startX1, startY1, endX1, endY1 and try to swipe in a way action.press as I posted above. It does the job for me in case of swiping in all directions - defined by start, end variables.